# How to Fix Your Position in Unity vr

Tags: unity-game-engine, htc-vive

Unity 3d is creating vive-only content.

I want to create an event that will not let the player move.

In the current player camera source code, I fixed the position value to 0 in the update section, but it does not perform the desired operation.

How do I fix my player's movements?

Comment: I strongly advice to **not** do this ever. The player moves in the physical real world ... you can do nothing against it. If you make the camera stuck to a certain position in Unity it will cause anything between dizziness and strong cybersickness since the virtual view does not longer respond to the physical movements - never a good idea...

Comment: It is a game where the user sits on a chair and watches an object at a predetermined angle. Because people have different heights, there is a problem that looks different from the set angle. 
So I try to fix the position by using only the angle of rotation.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Camera to only track rotations (3DoF) by using `UnityEngine.XR.InputTracking.disablePositionalTracking = false;`.
This will disable positional tracking, which is probably what you want.